# how to parse imageurl using xml in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, ios7

I'm very new to this technology.I do not know Xml parsing.After seeing few Documents I'm able to do some parsing.But now I'm unable to parse if it is like

```
<description>
<img src= some url><br/>
</description>
```

Please help me  my code:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"])
    {
        NSLog(@"attributes1: %@", attributeDict);
   }
```

I implemented it in did start element delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]) { NSstring url =[[attributeDict objectForKey:@"src"];}